# Android App which requires/uses Screen-PIN

Tags: android, passwords, screen, unlock

i would like to write an android application which requires the user to have the screen-pin activated and use the entered pin as a key to unlock the app. (this key is used for low-security encryption)

is there any way to get at least a hash of the entered pin? how can i proof/ensure that the screen-pin is activated and this will stay that way? is it possible to get a notification when the pin is entered and therefore the unlock-key for my app has changed?